# YouTube API v3 apiclient.errors.HttpError "No filter selected." - where do I select a filter?

Tags: python, youtube-api

My first attempt at setting up the Google `apiclient` for YouTube and by following the docs I made this as a test (didn't find a specific example for the YouTube API):

```
import json
from apiclient.discovery import build
service = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey = 'tralalala')
videos = service.videos()
request = videos.list(part = '7lCDEYXw3mM') # some video id
response = request.execute()
json.dumps(response, sort_keys = True, indent = 4)
```

I get this

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.parameter",
    "reason": "missingRequiredParameter",
    "message": "No filter selected.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": ""
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "No filter selected."
 }
}
```

Obviously I'm missing this `filter`, but I can't seem to find it anywhere in the docs [google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/youtube/v3/python/latest/index.html). My intent is to fetch a videos details by providing its `id`.

Comment: @pypat did try changing the value of `part` to `'id'`, but that produces the same error, thanks anyway :)

Comment: I think part should be "id" and the you need to provide another parameter q="7lCDEYXw3mM". That's just from quickly reading through the docs...hope it helps

Comment: @pypat you were almost right :), although the `q` has to be `id` and then the video id, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need at least one selector to list. 'id' is one of them. You can always check [YouTube API Samples](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/) project for reference.
Here's a [Python list usage](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/python/update_video.py) in one of examples.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for those links, somehow they weren't as easy to notice as I would've wished. It's always nice to get help from people developing this stuff :). One suggestion, the docs on appspot.com are very hard to read without any highlighting/clear indentation... Otherwise, keep up the good work :)

Answer (score 2):

Following @pypat's suggestion, I changed the attributes for my `list()` method

```
videos = service.videos()
request = videos.list(part = 'id', id = '7lCDEYXw3mM')
response = request.execute()
```

With both `part` and `id` being required to produce a result.

In order to get the full list or properties for a given video, the attribute `part` has to include a list of property groups

```
request = videos.list(part = 'id, snippet, contentDetails, statistics, status, topicDetails',
                      id = '7lCDEYXw3mM')
```

Comment: For those wondering how to get the youtube id video, when you insert (upload) a video to youtube and it is successful, a callback will be sent with the uploaded video's description.