# YouTube API v3 throws "No filter selected" error trying to list my subscriptions

Tags: c#, vb.net, google-api, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to retrieve a list containing all my **[subscriptions](https://www.youtube.com/subscription_manager)**, however, I'm getting an exception with this error message when calling `Await listRequest.ExecuteAsync()` in the source-code below:

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError No filter selected. Expected one of:
>   mySubscribers, id, mine, myRecentSubscribers, channelId [400] Errors [
>    Message[No filter selected. Expected one of: mySubscribers, id, mine,
>   myRecentSubscribers, channelId] Location[ - parameter]
>   Reason[missingRequiredParameter] Domain[youtube.parameter] ]

I read this, but I don't understand it at all:

- **[YouTube API v3 apiclient.errors.HttpError "No filter selected." - where do I select a filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735327/youtube-api-v3-apiclient-errors-httperror-no-filter-selected-where-do-i-sel)**

And the official reference:

- **[Subscriptions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#solicitud-http)**

---

I'm using the `YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube` scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube)

I'm using the "`snippet`" list selector to try list my subscriptions, I tried also with "`id,snippet,contentDetails`" joined.

And the autogenerated **client_secrets.json** file that I'm using to authenticate, has this content:

```
{
   "installed":{
      "client_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "project_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_secret":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "redirect_uris":[
         "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
         "http://localhost"
      ]
   }
}
```

---

I'm doing something wrong with the information provided above?, and, how I could fix this issue?.

Here is the relevant source-code:

Note that if I set the property `listRequest.Mine` to `True`, then it doesn't throws the exception, but then it finds Zero subscriptions.

C# (online translation):

```
public Task<List<Subscription>> GetSubscriptions(SubscriptionsResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum resultSorting)
{

   if (!(this.isAuthorizedB)) {
      throw new InvalidOperationException(this.authExceptionMessage);

   } else {
      SubscriptionsResource.ListRequest listRequest = Await this.client.Subscriptions.List("snippet");
      // listRequest.MySubscribers = False
      // listRequest.Mine = False
      listRequest.MaxResults = 50;
      listRequest.Order = resultSorting;

      SubscriptionListResponse searchResponse = Await listRequest.ExecuteAsync();

      List<Subscription> subscriptions = new List<Subscription>();

      while (true) {
         foreach (Subscription searchResult in searchResponse.Items) {
            subscriptions.Add(searchResult);
         }

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchResponse.NextPageToken)) {
            listRequest.PageToken = searchResponse.NextPageToken;
            searchResponse = listRequest.ExecuteAsync();
         } else {
            break; // TODO: might not be correct. Was : Exit Do
         }

      }

      return subscriptions;

   }

}
```

VB.NET (original):

```
Public Async Function GetSubscriptions(ByVal resultSorting As SubscriptionsResource.ListRequest.OrderEnum) As Task(Of List(Of Subscription))

    If Not (Me.isAuthorizedB) Then
        Throw New InvalidOperationException(Me.authExceptionMessage)

    Else
        Dim listRequest As SubscriptionsResource.ListRequest = Me.client.Subscriptions.List("snippet")
        With listRequest
            ' .MySubscribers = False
            ' .Mine = False
            .MaxResults = 50
            .Order = resultSorting
        End With

        Dim searchResponse As SubscriptionListResponse = Await listRequest.ExecuteAsync()

        Dim subscriptions As New List(Of Subscription)
        Do While True

            For Each searchResult As Subscription In searchResponse.Items
                subscriptions.Add(searchResult)
            Next searchResult

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchResponse.NextPageToken) Then
                listRequest.PageToken = searchResponse.NextPageToken
                searchResponse = Await listRequest.ExecuteAsync()
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If

        Loop

        Return subscriptions

    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Your code looks ok.  Do you by any chance have more then one YouTube account attached to your Google Account.   When you authenticate it will pop up and ask you to pick a YouTube account.  Did you select the correct one?

Comment: You need to send either channelId, id , mine or mySubscriptions those are the filters.  With out one of those you will get the No filter selected error.

Comment: @DaImTo Thanks for comment. I'm not sure if understood you, see, I have two different Google accounts, Youtube recognizes these accounts as two different accounts (not "attached"), it displays the main logged account and "Other accounts:... XXX". Actually the `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()` method is not showing any authentication popup, I pass to that method the email of the account on which I want to retrieve subscriptions, it authenticated once and no displayed the popup anymore. I have the same problem when trying to list my uploaded videos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok getting to long for a comment.  Note: The YouTube API is different its not like other Google APIs and it can be a bit weird to figure out.

When your code runs the authentication part

```
  UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                             , scopes
                                                                                             , userName
                                                                                             , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                             , new FileDataStore("Daimto.YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;
```

It will pop up and request access to your account.   Then it will ask which YouTube account

[image]

When you run your list

```
SubscriptionsResource.ListRequest listRequest = Await this.client.Subscriptions.List("snippet");          
      listRequest.Mine = true
      listRequest.MaxResults = 50;
      listRequest.Order = resultSorting;

      SubscriptionListResponse searchResponse = Await listRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

It is only going to show the results for the YouTube account you selected.   So the first thing you need to do is ensure that you are authenticating with the correct Google account and the correct YouTube account.  The account that you have currently picked has no subscriptions.

You will need to authenticate with each of the accounts passing an email wont authenticate.   You haven't posted your authentication code but in my code I just change "userName" and it will request access for a different user.  Its just a string you can send what ever you want to identify different users.  If you don't change the string then FileDatastore has a user already and it knows that so it wont ask for access again. My tutorial on filedatastore [Google .net FileDatastore Demystified](http://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/).    So change that and it will request access again :)

I also have a YouTube sample project I haven't played with it in a while but it might help.  [Google-dotnet-samples YouTube github](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/YouTube)

Comment: Seems that something was wrong on Google's server side or maybe in my data store folder, I ended seeying this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970917/why-is-google-calendar-api-oauth2-responding-with-insufficient-permission I then revoked my apps permission like is suggested the accepted answer, and then I authenticated my app again, and all works perfect, I'm using the same code with no changes. Thanks again!